# Constructive vs computable real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, computability, constructive-mathematics

I find it confusing that all of the following statements are true :

1. The computable real numbers are countable. $-\hspace{-3pt}-$ Alan Turing, "On Computable Numbers, with an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem"
2. In constructive analysis, the real numbers are uncountable. $-\hspace{-3pt}-$ Errett Bishop, *Foundations of Constructive Analysis*
3. "every mathematical statement [in constructive analysis] ultimately expresses the fact that if we perform certain computations within the set of positive integers, we shall get certain results" $-\hspace{-3pt}-$ *Ibid.*

Perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

I suppose I really have two questions. **In constructive analysis** :

1. Why isn't every real number computable?
2. How is it possible to construct an uncountable set?

Comment: What's the problem? Points 1 & 2 together imply that only a countable subset of the reals are computable (i.e., can be constructed using a finite algorithm).

Comment: @PM2Ring Doesn't point 3 imply that every real number is constructed by finite algorithms?

Comment: Bishop's brand of constructive analysis is, to simplify things a bit, classical analysis without excluded middle and the full axiom of choice (Bishop accepts countable choice). So much of the conclusions of classical analysis do go through. In other words, constructive does not mean computable.

Comment: Remark. You can count the computable real numbers in classical set theory, but this counting procedure is not a recursive enumeration: in a sense, the bijection between naturals and (programs coding) computable reals is itself not computable.If it was, you could get a new number by taking the diagonal and flipping digits. This resulting number would be different from every computable number, hence not computable. Yet you have just given the procedure to compute its $n$th digit for any $n$: take the first $n$ computable reals, compute their first $n$ digits, take the diagonal, flip the digits.

Comment: Such considerations resolve the apparent contradiction between statements (1), (2) and (3): the fact that the reals are uncountable in Bishop's constructive analysis does express an impossibility result regarding certain computations within the set of positive integers. The bijection whose existence is referenced in (1), however, is _not_ a computation.

Answer (score 5):

1. It is consistent with the constructive analysis that every real is computable. (In fact, it is consistent with intuitionistic ZF $\mathsf{IZF}$.) This follows from that the consistency of [Church's thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%27s_thesis_(constructive_mathematics)), which claims every total function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is computable.

   However, it does not mean constructive analysis can prove every real is computable. We know that classical analysis is a superset of constructive analysis (as a theory), that is, every statement that is provable from the constructive analysis is also a theorem of the classical analysis. And classical mathematics proves not every real is computable. Hence it would be accurate to say *whether every real is computable is independent of constructive analysis.*

   To add some comment, I think it does not mean Bishop is simply wrong. Bishop's constructive analysis is *minimal* in the sense that it is contained in classical analysis, Brouwer's intuitionistic mathematics, and *Recursive constructive analysis* (also known as Russian constructivism.) The latter one reflects the behavior of recursive mathematics, so Bishop's claim would be true in that sense.
2. $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable in the sense that there is no bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. The proof is available from Bishop's *Constructive analysis*. (Theorem 2.19 of Bishop and Bridges.) Here is a rough proof:

   > **Theorem.** There is no bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to an interval $[x_0,y_0]=\{z\in\mathbb{R}\mid x_0\le z\le y_0\}$.
   > *(Caution: $x\le y$ is *not* ($x< y$ or $x=y$.))*
   >
   > *Proof.* The proof uses diagonalization argument. Assume that $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function. We will find a Cauchy real $x\in [x_0,y_0]$ such that $f(n)\neq x$ for all $n$.
   > We will construct sequences of natural numbers $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ recursively such that
   >
   > 1. $x_0\le x_n\le x_m<y_m\le y_n\le y_0$ if $1\le n\le m$,
   > 2. $x_n>f(n)$ or $y_n<f(n)$, and
   > 3. $y_n-x_n<1/n$.
   >
   > Assume that $x_i$ and $y_i$ are given for all $i<n$.
   > Then we have either $f(n)>x_{n-1}$ or $f(n)<y_{n-1}$. *(This follows from the following constructively valid theorem: if $x<y$ are reals, then either $z<y$ or $x<z$.)*
   >
   > Assume that we have $f(n)>x_{n-1}$. (The remaining case is analogous.)
   > Choose a rational number $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $x_{n-1}<x_n<\min(a_n,y_{n-1})$ and $x_n<y_n<\min(a_n,y_{n-1},x_n+1/n)$. Then the mentioned inequalities are satisfied.
   >
   > Hence $(x_n)$ forms a Cauchy sequence of rational numbers. Let $x$ be a limit of $(x_n)$, then $x$ satisfies the desired properties.

   Note that the above proof makes use of the countable choice that Bishop accepted. As far as I know, it is open whether $\mathbb{R}$ is countable or not *without* the countable choice. Also, note that $\mathbb{R}$ can be *subcountable*, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$ can be an image of a *subset* of $\mathbb{N}$. (Unfortunately, I forgot whether the subcountability of $\mathbb{R}$ is compatible with $\mathsf{IZF}$, although I believe it is true.)

Comment: As for the uncertainty at the bottom: As per p. 21 [in this paper](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~rathjen/acend.pdf), it's consistent with $\mathsf{IZF}$ for ${\mathbb N}^{\mathbb N}$ to be subcountable. The class ${\mathcal P}{\mathbb N}$ is a set if you go as far as $\mathsf{IZF}$ does, but it can't be subcountable, by a diagonalization argument using most Separation schemas. The Cauchy sequences with modulus in ${\mathbb Q}^{\mathbb N}$ are a candidate for "the reals ${\mathbb R}$", but I'm afraid asking in terms of that word leaves too much room for debate what one is really talking about.

Comment: I'm confused about the "x≤y is not (x<y or x=y.)", what's the argument for this? It seems that less-equal here is by definition the disjunction between strictly less and equality?

Comment: @RasmusKällqvist $\le$ for real numbers has a different definition: $r\le s$ if and only if $r_n$ and $s_n$ represents $r$ and $s$ respectively then $r_n\le s_n$ for all $n$. On the other hand, $r<s$ if and only if the difference $s_n-r_n$ has a non-zero lower bound.

Comment: @RasmusKällqvist Of course, $r\le s$ implies $r<s$ or $r=s$ *classically*, but we are in the *constructive* mathematics, and many things do not behave as we know in this context.

Answer (score -1):

A real number $x$ is computable if there exists a program $P(n)$ that on input $n$ outputs the decimal expansion of $x$ up to the $n$th digit. For example, $\pi$ is one such  computable number - you can approximate $\pi$ as close as you want with a computer.

From this we can deduce $1$. Each computer program can be specified by a unique integer (it's binary representation), and hence there are a countable number of such programs, and therefore at most a countable number of computable real numbers.

However as $2$ says, the real numbers are uncountable. You can find a classical diagonalization proof of this fact [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

So if the real numbers are uncountable but computable numbers are countable then there must exist uncountably many real numbers which are not computable. Examples of uncomputable real numbers are rather exotic - they do not usually appear in natural problems.

However that does not mean they are sparse - indeed since every interval of the real line contains uncountable many numbers it must contain uncountable many uncomputable numbers. One example of an uncomputable number is [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant).

The third statement you cite is the most sophisticated. Essentially, uncomputable numbers are not operational - you cannot use them in ordinary calculations. So for all practical purposes you could just work with the set of computable real numbers - and that is what constructive analysts do. Computable real numbers are algebraically closed - every reasonable operation you do with them will result in another computable numbers. That is the essence of the statement.

Regarding your question on how to build uncountable sets - if a set $S$ is countably infinite, then the set of all subsets of $S$ is uncountable. This is [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

Comment: -1 because you did not answer my question, which is specific to *constructive analysis.* Also you didn't say anything I didn't already know.

Comment: @simplejack your three questions were 1) how can all these be true?,  2) why isn't every real number computable and 3) how can you construct an uncountable set? I answered respectively that 1) there are real numbers which are uncomputable, but constructivists do not use them, 2) because programs are countable and 3) Cantor's theorem illustrates one such example.

If you have any remaining questions, I'd be happy to walk you through it.

Comment: There is a difference between *classical* real numbers and *constructive* real numbers. Everything you said is classical. I am very familiar with classical mathematics but not with constructive mathematics. So: (1) How can you *construct* a number which is not computable? (2) How can you *construct* an uncountable set? It isn't clear to me even how to construct the power set of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @simplejack I see, I misunderstood what you meant by construct. Generally, we say that you can cosntruct a set of numbers (though the typical nomenclature is saying that the set is *decidable*) if you can write a program $D(x)$ such that $D(x)$ outputs true iff $x$ is a member of the set and $D(x)$ stops on a finite number of steps for every output.

Answer (score -5):

1.Because there is at least one real number that is not computable.

2.
Step 1 : 0.0 , 0.1

Step 2 : 0.00 , 0.01 , 0.10 , 0.11

Step 3 : 0.000 , 0.001 , 0.010 , 0.100 , 0.011 , 0.101 , 0.110  , 0.111

step n : 0.(all combinations 1,0 of length n)

continue above indefinitely in binary to get all values in the interval 0,1.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: @MaxHeiber : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3900368/constructing-real-numbers-and-why-every-real-is-not-computable